# Set default PostgreSQL role on Windows

Tags: postgresql

I want to set the default role of my PostgreSQL installation on Windows when running the `psql` command.

I believe I have correctly created the role with the following commands according to [an answer in another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276875/19692949):

```bash
# Log in the root role
psql -U postgres

# Create role
create user Mathe with password '123';
```

If I run `create user` again I get:

> ERROR: role "mathe" already exists

When I run `psql` again with no arguments I get:

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "Mathe" does not exist

Which, I believe, is because of the first uppercase letter. How can I change that default role?

---

According to the comments, I have attempted this to solve the above issue with running `psql` with nothing:

```
postgres-# ALTER ROLE Mathe
postgres-# SET LOGIN = true
postgres-# SET NOLOGIN = false
```

Any ideas why I get exactly the same output as above?

---

I have tried the exact @Luuk's command:

```
C:\Users\Mathe>psql -U postgres
psql (16.0)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# ALTER ROLE "mathe" RENAME TO "Mathe"
postgres-# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------
 hydroper  |
 mathe     |
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS
```

I have tried `psql` as follows:

```
C:\Users\Mathe>psql -U mathe
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "mathe" does not exist

C:\Users\Mathe>psql -U Mathe
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "Mathe" does not exist
```

Comment: [What is Create User and Create Role in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490683/what-is-create-user-and-create-role-in-postgresql), so you can do something like `ALTER ROLE  mathe RENAME TO  Mathe`  (see: [Using the PostgreSQL ALTER ROLE to modify attributes of roles](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-alter-role/#:~:text=Use%20ALTER%20ROLE%20role_name%20option,default%20for%20a%20configuration%20variable.))

Comment: `mathe` is not the same as `"Mathe"`.

Comment: @Luuk I have looked at these questions you linked now, but I have not yet understood how to change that `LOGIN` attribute. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already connected to the server, check the existing database(s) and role(s) under the running server.
To check existing databases:

```
postgres=# \l
```

To check existing roles:

```
postgres=# \du
```

If role `Mathe` is not listed under roles, you can create it.PostgreSQL by default converts unquoted identifiers (such as usernames) to lowercase. This behavior is why you observe that the user "Mathe" is listed as "mathe" when you use the `\du` command. To create `Mathe` correctly:

`postgres=# CREATE USER "Mathe";`

Then to switch to role `Mathe` from your current role by running

`psql -U Mathe`

The success of the psql command will depend on the existence of the `Mathe` role, the accessibility of the server you are trying to connect to, and the authentication rules defined on the server.
If the command `psql -U Mathe` fails, go back to `postgres=#` then create a database with user Mathe.

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE "Mathe" WITH OWNER "Mathe";
```

Then confirm if this is successful.

```
SELECT current_user;
```

or

```
SELECT current_role;
```

Alternatively, if you do

```
psql -U Mathe -d Mathe
```

that connects you to the specified database `Mathe` through the user `Mathe`.

Answer (score 0):

2 choices:

1. `psql -U Mathe`
2. 

```
$ psql -U postgres

postgres=#> ALTER ROLE "mathe" RENAME TO "Mathe"
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 Mathe     | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
postgres=# QUIT

$ psql
```

P.S. The attributes on your system might be different....

Comment: My system insists in renaming `Mathe` to `mathe` ^^'

Comment: Please show the output of your attempt to rename.